# Run Service twice

Tags: java, android, android-service

Quick question:

I made a service to monitor an RFID-Reader, if it reads something it filters the ID n stuff, which is working.

Now i have 2 readers on my board, and i need to listen to both readers.
I thought that the best way to do so is starting a service for every reader i use, because there might be even more readers in the future. But there's this part in the doc about `startService(intent);`:

"If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running."

So so what happens is the 2nd time i try to start the service it just changes the existing one to the 2nd port i called it with.

**Is there any way to start the service twice or do i have to come up with something else?**

Here's how i start the service:

```
private static final String devicePathIn = "/dev/ttyUSB1";
private static final String devicePathOut = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
```

In onCeate in the MainActivity:

```
startServiceOnPort(devicePathOut);
startServiceOnPort(devicePathIn);
```

And the method startServiceOnPort:

```
private void startServiceOnPort(String port){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RFIDService.class);
    intent.putExtra("port", port);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Obviously only the 2nd reader i start the service on is able to read tags.

Kind Regards

Noudan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot start a second instance of your service.  You should modify your service to support multiple RFID readers using threads.  Sending a `startService` to a service which is already running will just deliver the new `Intent`.

Comment: Jeah, i was afraid that would be the case. Thanks for clarification.